# Fatal error & PDOException em SELECT POO PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando realizar um select, porém recebo as seguintes mensagens referente a mesma linha:

```
Fatal error: in C:\wamp\www\curso\Crud.class.php on line 24
PDOException: in C:\wamp\www\curso\Crud.class.php on line 24
```

Os erros referem-se ao seguinte método:

```
  public function findAll() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";
        $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

No qual a linha 24 seria `$stmt->execute();`

Estou tentando retornar os valores do `fetchAll` com um `foreach`, da seguinte forma:

```
<?php foreach ($usuario->findAll() as $key => $value): ?>

<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->nome; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->login; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $value->senha; ?></td>                                    
</tr>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Classe DB:**

```
<?php

define('URL', 'http://localhost/t');
        const DB_NAME = 'curso';
        const DB_USER = 'root';
        const DB_PASS = '';
        const DB_HOST = 'localhost';

class DB {

    private static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function prepare($sql) {
        return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
    }

}
```

Definição da classe **Crud**:

```
abstract class Crud extends DB {
```

Definição da classe **Usuarios**:

```
class Usuarios extends Crud {
```

A definição da tabela fica pela classe usuarios:
 `protected $table = 'users`';

Estou me baseando nesse [crud genérico](https://github.com/andrewesteves/php-oo-praticando/blob/master/classes/Crud.php).

Caso necessite de outras partes do codigo, irei disponibilizar.
Obs.: Sou leigo em PDO, iniciei meus estudos sobre tal a dois dias, então peço desculpas de forma adiantada por erros simples.

Comment: a propriedade `$table` está definida na sua classe e ela existe no DB ?

Comment: Existe sim. Irei preencher a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: Eu dei um try/catch e foi exibido a seguinte mensagem: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Tabela 'curso.users' não existe

Comment: @ThiagoBarros Já tens a tua resposta, a tabela não existe na base de dados!

Comment: é ai que ta.. a tabela existe sim!

Comment: Perdão. O erro estava na declaração de um outro metodo na classe DB..